# Can you dynamically create an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I currently have a function that is called multiple times because it recursivly decends through my program. Every time that function is called I am trying to create a new array. As my program decends it runs another function that adds items into that new array. Once all those items are added into that array I am then trying to push that array into another array that stores all my different arrays containg different elements.

For Example:

```
var staticarray = [];

function createarray(){
    if(test == true){
        //creates new array
    }
    additems();
    //pushes array to staticarray 
} 

function additems(){
    if(anothertest == true){ 
        //adds items into new array
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: how about if we start learning JS  before asking this type of questions? http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Comment: The code you've given is too vague. I can't see any recursion happening. JavaScript can appear deceptively simple at first glance, but I think it would really help you to read through a good introduction, for example, https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Create array
let myArray = ["1"];
// Add Item
myArray.push("2");

// Add Items of another array
let otherArray= ["3", "4"];
myArray.push([...otherArray]);
```